# System disk error, but only on restart

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, boot, multi-boot

I have a functioning Windows 10 system dual booting with Ubuntu Linux. After replacing the system drive, I can start the system from a cold boot just fine, it finds GRUB, and allows me to choose the OS. If I am in Windows however and select 'restart', when it power cycles,  the system yields 'Non-system disk or system disk error'. Powering off and back on again, the system boots as usual.

What is going on with this installation?

Comment: Have you [disabled Fast Startup in Windows](https://help.uaudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/213195423-How-To-Disable-Fast-Startup-in-Windows-10)?

Comment: This appears to be related to hibernation, which is disabled for this machine.

Comment: Try to disable Fast Startup.

Comment: 'Fast Startop' option is not available in the usual location. On some research this appears to be because I have disabled the Hibernation feature for this machine, so presumably, Fast Startup is not enabled.